# how to send a customized autoreply to an Outlook meeting request?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

My Outlook calendar is visible to others in free/busy mode (they see an empty slot when there is no meeting, a blue bar when busy, a purple one when away and a hashed one when tentative).

This indication, somehow, is not crystal-clear to some and they still try to book on a "busy" field.

**I would like to know whether it is possible to send a customized autoreply when receiving a meeting request which overlaps with a busy/tentative/away slot?**

I would nicely explain that the blue and purple mean *"I am busy, please look for another place"* and the hashed one *"I will let you know shortly if I can rearrange my schedule and free this slot"*. Ability to add pictures welcome.

I do not know much about the internals of Outlook but I am willing to learn, thank you for any pointers to the right direction.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Sorry,  forgot to mention the version : Outlook 2013

Comment: It depends on the organization and people in real life. I am looking for a technical solution,  though (to be reused in other cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way in Outlook to include custom replies based on the free/busy schedule types.

You can auto accept/decline meetings as a checkbox option under file, options. You can also auto decline meetings that are already taking place during that time. You do not have an option to include any personal communication with this decline.

If you try to use rules wizard to rig your own template response to meeting requests and updates, you will be able to send auto replies, but your meeting requests can not be auto processed and you have to manually accept or decline.